# Is the structure (gerund+of+something) correct in this sentence: "Celebratory drinking of alcohol was restricted in 1600s in Britain."

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-construction, idiomatic-language, gerunds

This is from the BBC (simplified version of a longer sentence).

**"Celebratory drinking of alcohol was restricted by them in 1600s in Britain."**

The structure **"Celebratory drinking of alcohol was...."** sounds not correct to me. I don't know why, but for some reason, I have a feeling that it should have been **"Drinking alcohol in a celebratory way was ......."** or **"Drinking for celebratory purposes was ....."** (omit alcohol) to make it sound more natural.

I thought a lot about why it sounds not correct to me. I think it might be because the noun form of the verb **"to drink"** is **"drinking"**. It does not sound like a seperate noun. So, rather than **"Drinking of alcohol ......."**, you expect a structure like **"Drinking alcohol was ...."**. The gerund form does not seem to go well with the **"of"**.

I thought of another sentence with the same sentence structure to see if all same cases sound weird. For instance this sentence **"The arbitrary use of shampoo might be harmful".** sounds perfect. The only difference is that it is not using the gerund form of the verb **"to use"**, it is using a seperate noun form **"The use of something"**. If it used the gerund form "**The arbitrary using of shampoo ....."** it would again sound weird to me.

So, the problem seems to lie in the fact that **"to drink"** does not have a seperate noun word for it. And the gerund form **(Drinking of something)** does not go well with the **"of".** The preposition **"of"** requires a noun **"something of something"** not **"gerund of something"**

I don't know, maybe I am wrong as I am not a native speaker. So, I want to ask: Do you think **"Celebratory drinking of alcohol...."** is correct in grammar?

Comment: Celebratory is an adjective modifying the noun in gerund form 'drinking'. It's totally fine.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, Thanks Michael, the problem is not about the celebratory, it is about "drinking of alcohol". You drink something, you would not drink of something, would you?

Comment: But you 'have a drink of' something. The construction is perfectly normal.

Comment: @KateBunting, thanks, yes 'have a drink of' something is perfectly normal, but in the sentence it is "drinking of alcohol ..." not "a drink of alcohol".

Comment: I meant that **[verb]ing of [noun]** was perfectly normal! c.f. the poem [Naming of Parts](https://www.poetrybyheart.org.uk/poems/naming-of-parts/) and the song _The leaving of Liverpool_.

Comment: @Kate Bunting, thanks again. I checked the link you provided. Yes, that is exactly a good example to my question. And now I am fully satisfied that my question was understood and the answer is provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am not a native speaker either.

Nothing about that construction appears wrong or even unusual to me.

This use of "of" is meaning 9a in the [Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/of) ("indicate the object of an action denoted or implied by the preceding noun") or meaning 9 in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/of#Preposition) ("forming the objective genitive").

These dictionaries do not have any examples specifically with a gerund, but a gerund can function like any other noun. You mention "arbitrary use of shampoo", but the difference between that and "drinking" is that there is no other way to turn "to drink" into a noun that means the action of drinking than "drinking", while there is for "to use".

The [Wikipedia article on the gerund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund#%22Gerund%22_clauses_with_a_specified_subject) gives the example of: *Brown's deft painting of his daughter is a delight to watch.*

The same Wikipedia article also contains a live example of such usage: *Since Afrikaans has by and large lost explicit morphological **marking of the infinitive form** of the verb, verb stems are used as gerunds*.

This is completely normal usage of English, as far as I can tell. There is nothing special about gerunds.